# Transfer between Split and Split Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, split, spu

How do you get from Split to Split Airport? The web is filled with spam regarding this and the websites for the options lack timetables etc.

Comment: There is some info on [the website of the airport](http://www.split-airport.hr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=185&Itemid=176&lang=en). I don't know about direct buses, but we noticed in Split that bus stops don't really have usable timetables, as they only show the departures from the first stop, not the current one.

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Split/Split-Airport-SPU) lists bus (Line 37, every 20 mins), taxi and Uber, amongst other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shuttle Busses

There are busses that depart from the main station and two companies occupy the route;

- AK ([to the airport](http://www.ak-split.hr/en/departures-from-split/), [from the airport](http://www.ak-split.hr/en/arrivals-to-split/))
- [Pleso](http://www.plesoprijevoz.hr/en)

Price and route is the same so just pick the one where there's a lot of people.

### Local Busses

There's also the [Sukoišan Bus Terminal](https://goo.gl/maps/w21d3GFs8RPFGtyi7) with airport connections, namely bus 37. *Trogir is a town west of the airport, Split is east.*

- Promet ([to the airport](http://www.promet-split.hr/en/timetables/urban-area-split/linijaid/8729), [from the airport](http://www.promet-split.hr/en/timetables/urban-area-split/linijaid/8730))

### Taxis

There are taxis just north of the bus station (3 meters) and you should always ask for a fixed price, e.g. 250 kn. Else it can get much more expensive. You might have to ask around to get a fixed/good price but that's no problem, there's no "taxi queue" there that you might find at other places.